# how divided times in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In database i have date,start time and end time.now i want to divided these times into 15 mins difference.IF start time is 4:00 AM and end time is 6:00 AM then these times divided into 4:00 AM-(to)4:15AM min,4:15 AM-4:30 AM etc.
in the below i gave some codes.please help me or give me the procedure should i follow to solved this problem

controllar code:

```
 function fetch_availableime(){
        $doctor_id = $this->input->post('doctor_id');
        $date = $this->input->post('dates');
        $started_time = $this->appointment_model->get_started_time($doctor_id,$date);
        $ended_time = $this->appointment_model->get_ended_time($doctor_id,$date);
        if ($started_time > $ended_time) {
            for ($i=$started_time; $i <$ended_time ; $i++) { 
                $con_times = date('i:sa',strtotime('+15 minutes',strtotime($started_time)));
                echo $con_times;
            }
        }
}
```

Model Code:

```
function get_started_time($doctor_id,$date){
        $this->db->select('mstime');
        $this->db->from('availability');
        $this->db->where('doctor_id',$doctor_id);
        $this->db->where('date',$date);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

function get_ended_time($doctor_id,$date){
    $this->db->select('metime');
    $this->db->from('availability');
    $this->db->where('doctor_id',$doctor_id);
    $this->db->where('date',$date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: it is important to include, in the question, what is currently wrong with your code. and a sample of your `$started_time` and `$ended_time` as it comes in from the database. i would pay particular attention to `if ($started_time > $ended_time) {`. my guess is you need to conform these to something. try to strtotime them

Comment: if i implement this code it doesnot show anything....$started_time and $ended_time gives me values and if ($started_time > $ended_time)  means started_time have to big value then $ended_time

Comment: yes, but it probably doesn't show anything because the if statement evaluated to false. hence why i asked to echo or var_dump those variables.

Answer (score 0):

result() returns array of object it is better to use row() for single row then access time with object

```
return $query->row();
```

then in controller use

```
$started_time=$started_time->mstime;
$ended_time=$ended_time->metime;
```

and for compare two dates you should use strtotime(), for more info see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209554/php-compare-two-date-and-time)

Comment: i am trying but its not working........

 function fetch_availableime(){
        $doctor_id = $this->input->post('doctor_id');
        $date = $this->input->post('dates');
        $started_time = $this->appointment_model->get_started_time($doctor_id,$date);
        $ended_time = $this->appointment_model->get_ended_time($doctor_id,$date);

        while(strtotime($start_time->mstime;) < strtotime($end_time->metime)) {
                $con_times = $start_time('i:sa',strtotime('+15 minutes',strtotime($started_time)));
                echo $con_times;
        
        }
}

Comment: ok i want to see the result of var_dump($started_time = $this->appointment_model->get_started_time($doctor_id,$date)) , to know what is returning from query